# export R list into Julia via JSON

Tags: json, r, julia

suppose I have this list in R

```
x = list(a=1:3,b=8:20)
```

and I write this to a json file on disk with

```
library(jsonlite)
cat(toJSON(x),file="f.json")
```

how can I use the Julia JSON package to read that? Can I?

```
# Julia
using JSON
JSON.parse("/Users/florianoswald/f.json")
```

gives a mistake - I guess it expects a json string.

Any alternatives? I would benefit from being able to pass a list (i.e. a nested structure) rather than tabular data. thanks!

Comment: You might want to try `JSON.parsefile` rather than `JSON.parse` in the Julia snippet

Comment: yeah that's what common sense would suggest right? `JSON.parsefile ERROR: parsefile not defined`

Comment: It sounds like you might have an outdated version of the `JSON` package. What does `Pkg.status()` say? Try doing `Pkg.checkout("JSON")` and giving it another go.

Comment: ha. that worked! can you explain that to me please? I installed this literally 30 mins ago with `Pkg.add("JSON")`, and also did a `Pkg.update()` right now. it said all is up to date. what is different from `Pkg.checkout("JSON")`? thanks!

Comment: `Pkg.update()` gets you the latest release on METADATA (the Julia package registry), `Pkg.checkout()` gets you the latest master from the package's git repo.

Comment: The reason you probably had an outdated `JSON` is because you probably had an outdated METADATA. `Pkg.update()` fetches the latest METADATA as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with the current version of JSON you can use Julia's `readall` method to get a string from a file.

`Pkg.clone("JSON")` will get you the latest development version of JSON.jl (as opposed to the latest *released* version) – it seems `parsefile` is not released yet.